# Unable to use setter even though its not final in lombok

Tags: java, lombok

Unable to use setter even though its not final in lombok

```
class Foo {
..
    @Builder.Default
    @JsonProperty(REGISTRATION_DATE)
    private LocalDate registrationDate = LocalDate.now();
}

Foo foo = Foo.builder().build();
foo.setRegistrationDate(LocalDate.of(2015,01,01));
```

registrationDate is never set to 2015-01-01 even though we are setting LocalDate.now()

Comment: are you getting any error? or is it just it is not taken the date?, how do you know it? could you put a @ToString annotation and try to print the object as an example?

Comment: no error, always take the LocalDate.now()

Comment: Have you checked  generated class?